# Prevent direct access to files with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

Ok, I am using codeigniter and I have a secure login section. Inside the login users are able to download files.

What I need to do is stop people been able to access the file directly. I figure there will be a way using .htaccess to check for a authenticated variable that I could set in the POST array or something similar.

Any pointers would be good, was a bit of a hard topic to google because I'm not really sure what the best way to do  it is.

Thanks.

Comment: The question is not specific to CodeIgniter. I would tag it as PHP instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good Google would be:
php secure file download

Some helpful results I found for you:

To keep the files inside your webroot and password protect the directory they are inside of, and then use PHP to push the file(s) to the browser for download: http://www.nopersonal.info/aboutkateers/php_stuff/php_force_download.php

Or, if you have access to a directory above your web root:
http://forums.tizag.com/showthread.php?t=893

Comment: Thanks, think the first solution is best for me. I will implement .htpasswd and see how I go. Should be straight forward though.